# Use of Group Concat Repeat region

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my DB structure.
Table name LOPList:

[image: a busy cat]

I have this SQL:

```
select LOPID, EmpId,
       max(case when LOPStatus = 'Y' then TimeUpdated end) as time_start,
       max(case when LOPStatus = 'N' then TimeUpdated end) as time_end
from MultipleLOPStatus
where JobID = 83
group by LOPID
```

This results out to be

```
LOPID | EmpId    | time_start                | time_end
33    |   28     | 2016-03-27T09:33:05-03:00 |  2016-03-27T11:49:17-03:00`
```

I want results to be :

```
 LOPID |    EmpId    | time_start                | time_end
33     |    28       | 2016-03-27T09:23:17-03:00 | 2016-03-27T09:31:59-03:00
33     |    28       | 2016-03-27T09:32:30-03:00 | 2016-03-27T11:49:17-03:00
33     |    30       | 2016-03-27T09:33:05-03:00 | 2016-03-27T11:48:53-03:00 `
```

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Why should this results be the output?

Comment: You can `GROUP BY` more than one column. But from your expected result it's not clear which colums should be in the GROUP-BY-list.

Comment: This type of matching is quite painful to do in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just wanted to get the time_end for each corresponding time_start. In this case you don't need to use conditional aggregation , you can achieve this with a correlated query :

```
SELECT s.LOPID, s.EmpId,s.timeUpdated as time_start,
       (SELECT MIN(timeUpdated) FROM MultipleLOPStatus t
        WHERE s.LOPID = t.LOPID and t.empid = s.empid and t.LOPStatus = 'N'
          AND t.timeUpdated > s.TimeUpdated) as time_end
from MultipleLOPStatus s
where s.JobID = 83
 AND s.LOPStatus = 'Y'
```

Comment: This would give the same row -- 534 -- for the adjacent "Y"s.